# upgrading qooxdoo 5.0.x application to the current version based on NodeJS

Tags: qooxdoo

How do I upgrade a previoud Qooxdoo application 5.0.3 to a new application I created with the qooxdoo compiler ?

After creating the new app with the qooxdoo compiler and replacing the source code we get a huge number of errors.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What kind of errors?  The compiler is backwards compatible (although you have to create a new compile.json to replace the old generator's config.json), the easiest way to get started is usually the way you've described, i.e. to create a new app with `qx create` and then move your source code into it

Comment: PS there is an active community on Gitter: https://gitter.im/qooxdoo/qooxdoo